# Method to update properties in ios swift code while keeping the fuction pure as possible and testable?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

Long time IOS developer/tinkerer here. I mostly taught myself programming, OBJ-C back in the day and now Swift. So apologies in advance if things I ask are too basic, its partly because I may not be well versed on some fundamentals.

I am currently working on an app. Alongside it I have been reading a fair bit on writing testable code and testing in general. I am not talking about purely TDD but I would like the libraries that I am creating for the app to have a good testset available. Partly because its good practice and partly because its soemthing I want to learn to do better.

So here goes, in my app class(es) I have a number of functions that take in parameters and give an output (as you do!). However, a number of these functions also make changes to class properties as data in these properties will be used in other class functions. For example:

```
class SomeClass() {
    var someArrayProperty: [String] = []
    var someInputParameter: String

     init(input: String) {
         //some initialisation code
         self.someInputParameter = input

         //Call function to build object
         let object = self.buildObject(inputParameter: self.someInputParameter)
     }

     func buildObject(inputParameter: String) -> SomeObject {
         let objectToReturn = SomeObject(withInputParameter: inputParameter)
         let stringToAddToArray = "Object 1 created"
         self.someArrayProperty.append(stringToAddToArray)
         return objectToReturn
     }
}
```

From what I have read about the testing, the code should ideally be such that it should do one job and not change something outside of the code as it becomes untestable for complex code. Here, the issue I have is that I am directly changing the `someArrayProperty` from within the method, i.e. changing something outside of the method.

Although its not an issue for the code and everything works fine, I would like to understand what do you guys feel about things like this from a testing point of view in your own code? And what pattern/changes you generally follow in your own code to avoid it?

Again, apologies if its too basic a question but I think it will help me fill in gaps in my knowledge to be able to write more beautiful code rather than something that just works and breaks next time a minor update is done somwhere. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So if your function is called `buildObject`, it should do job inside it and have no `return` value. But if you call it `buildedObject`, it should return constructed object. You can read more about in [Apple Naming Methods documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html).

And so your code should look like this:

```
class SomeClass() {
    var someArrayProperty: [String] = []
    var someInputParameter: String

     init(input: String) {
         //some initialisation code
         self.someInputParameter = input

         //Call function to build object
         let object = self.buildedObject(inputParameter: self.someInputParameter)

         // Other code which modifies data
         let stringToAddToArray = "Object 1 created"
         self.someArrayProperty.append(stringToAddToArray)
     }

     func buildedObject(inputParameter: String) -> SomeObject {
         let objectToReturn = SomeObject(withInputParameter: inputParameter)
         return objectToReturn
     }
}
```